# Swift/XCODE - Unable to press(touch) fast on a UIButton

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibutton, touch

i have a singe view screen , with a button inside that covers the whole screen.
i'm not able to press it very fast,it's stuck sometimes.
i have played the game Piano Tiles and you can press fast on the buttons with no stucks.
so this is my questions : 
1) is it possible to press very fast multiply times on a UIButton?
2) What is touch down repeat option when connecting the button to the code(the action)

i have set the action to touch down so it will be as fast as i can but still dosent flow right.
any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not run into that problem before, but you may want to consider adding a UITapGestureRecognizer to your ViewController's main view, and using that for detecting your taps instead of a UIButton.

[Here's Apple's official docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITapGestureRecognizer).

[This is a also a decent tutorial on it using Swift](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76020/using-uigesturerecognizer-with-swift-tutorial). I'd recommend the Programmatic UIGestureRecognizers for a quick setup and go.